# Closure issue with KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, closures

It seems I have a closure problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtortola/NMHQ6/

The code adds some bars to the screen and it should reduce the size of all of them, but it only happens in the last one.

```
var bar = function(start){
    me = {};
    me.width = ko.observable(start);

   var countDown = function(milliseconds, step, callback){
        callback(milliseconds);
        if(milliseconds>0)
            setTimeout(function(){ countDown(milliseconds-step,step,callback);}, step+10);
    };

   countDown(start, 1, function(m){me.width(m); });

    return me;
}

var viewModel = function(){
    var me ={};
    me.bars = ko.observableArray();
    for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
        me.bars.push(bar(300));
    }
    return me;
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

But I cannot find the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are missing the `var` keyword in the `bar` function and so, your `me` variable is declared in the global scope. For this reason, and since in javascript objects are passed by reference,  your `me.bars` is filled with the same `content`.

A simple fix will be :

```
var bar = function(start){
    var me = {};
    me.width = ko.observable(start);

   var countDown = function(milliseconds, step, callback){
        callback(milliseconds);
        if(milliseconds>0)
            setTimeout(function(){ countDown(milliseconds-step,step,callback);}, step+10);
    };

   countDown(start, 1, function(m){me.width(m); });

    return me;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I must be blind. Thanks a million.